# Unity: How to change toggle in toggle group programmatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have, in my game, a toggle group to change difficulties and inside a script I want to change the active toggle. For example, by default, the game is set to normal, in my script I want to change the difficulty to easy, how can I accomplish this?

```
public ToggleGroup difficultyToggle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    difficultyToggle = config.difficulty;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are trying to do, but from what i understand:

You have a toggle group for different game difficulties. Toggle groups are used to have only one option active at a time which is exactly what you would want in that case. In order to change a setting though you would need to change the IsOn value of the button.

```
public Toggle toggle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    toggle.isOn = false;
}
```

If you meant you want to change the difficulty when the toggle is changed you can add a function that gets triggered when the toggle value (isOn) is changed.

The below link will explain what this does. Read the Events part:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Toggle.html

Answer (score 0):

toggleGroup.NotifyToggleOn(easyModeToggle);

will not work, however addressing the toggle directly with this:

easyModeToggle.isOn = true;

will work, the toggle will switch on and notiify the others in the group to switch off, but of course you need to have a reference to the right toggle in code, and if you're linking references to UI elements in the inspector, you might as well just select the correct toggle to be on at startup by setting it on in the inspector in the scene view.